# SQL: Replacing a column value with another tables column, if a foreign key exists

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am querying `table a` for each row's name, however, if the row has a `bID` value (this will be a foreign key to table b's id), I want to replace the name value from `table a` with `table b`. How can I do this?

```
table a
---------
id / bID (may be null) / name

table b
---------
id / name

SELECT a.id as id, a.name as name, a.bid
FROM `table a` as a
LEFT JOIN `table b` as b ON a.bID = b.id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `ISNULL` on the 'b' table's name should suffice. You could use `COALESCE` instead if you want which can also take multiple parameters, not just two as with `ISNULL`.

```
SELECT a.id as id, ISNULL(b.name, a.name) as name, a.bid
FROM `table a` as a
LEFT JOIN `table b` as b ON a.bID = b.id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: If that is the case then you must not be using MS SQL, which I assumed and you didn't mention in you question/tagging. I always assume MS SQL as that's what I mainly use unless the poster has specified otherwise. What RDMS are you using out of curiosity?

Comment: My bad. I thought MySQL was the norm. I'm using MySQL.